# How to format a long adding thousands separator on Arduino

Tags: c++, c, formatting, arduino, long-integer

I'm developing a project on Arduino that parses some JSON data from a remote web API displaying it on a 16x2 LCD.

I would like to format a long parsed with [TextFinder](http://www.arduino.cc/playground/Code/TextFinder) adding the thousands separator (a comma separator would be fine).

In a nutshell, how do I code the `formatLong` function?

```
long longToBeFormatted = 32432423;

formattedLong = formatLong(longToBeFormatted); //How to implement this?

lcd.print(formattedLong) // formattedLong is a string
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what toolset gets used on Arduino. Sometimes the library will support a non-standard 'thousands grouping' flag - the single-quote character is the typical extension:

```
printf("%'ld",long_val);
```

If your library doesn't support this, something like the following might do:

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>

size_t strlcpy( char* dest, char const* src, size_t dest_size);

size_t format_long( long x, char* buf, size_t bufsize)
{
    // This code assumes 32-bit long, is that the
    // case on Arduino?  Modifying it to be able to
    // handle 64-bit longs (or to not care) should be
    // pretty straightforward if that's necessary.

    char scratch[sizeof("-2,147,483,648")];
    char* p = scratch + sizeof(scratch);    // Work from end of buffer
    int neg = (x < 0);

    // Handle a couple special cases
    if (x == 0) {
        return strlcpy( buf, "0", bufsize);
    }
    if (x == INT_MIN) {
        // Lazy way of handling this special case
        return strlcpy( buf, "-2,147,483,648", bufsize);
    }

    // Work with positive values from here on
    if (x < 0) x = -x;

    int group_counter = 3;
    *(--p) = 0; // Null terminate the scratch buffer

    while (x != 0) {
        int digit = x % 10;
        x = x / 10;

        assert( p != &scratch[0]);
        *(--p) = "0123456789"[digit];

        if ((x != 0) && (--group_counter == 0)) {
            assert( p != &scratch[0]);
            *(--p) = ',';
            group_counter = 3;
        }
    }

    if (neg) {
        assert( p != &scratch[0]);
        *(--p) = '-';
    }
    return strlcpy(buf, p, bufsize);
}


/*
    A non-optimal strlcpy() implementation that helps copying string
    without danger of buffer overflow.

    This is provided just in case you don't have an implementation
    so the code above will actually compile and run.
*/
size_t strlcpy( char* dest, char const* src, size_t dest_size)
{
    size_t len = strlen(src);

    if (dest_size == 0) {
        // nothing to copy - just return how long the buffer should be
        //  (note that the return value doens't include the null terminator)
        return len;
    }

    size_t tocopy = (dest_size <= len) ? dest_size-1 : len;

    memmove( dest, src, tocopy);
    dest[tocopy] = 0;

    return len;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. The grouping does not work, I've also tried it locally on my Mac with gcc 4.0 without success, do you know any documentation about that flag?. The `format_long` function works great without the need of using the `strlcpy` local function. Long type on Arduino is 32-bit so your function fits well. One more question: why the `format_long` function need a `bufsize` parameter?

Comment: I'm a fan of having callers specify the buffer sizes so the functions can avoid overrunning the end of the buffer (that's why I used `strlcpy()`).  An alternative is to have the function dynamically allocate the buffer of whatever size is required and  return that to the caller. But on projects involving small devices like arduino, dynamic memory is often not acceptable to use.  Of course that really depends on the requirements of your specific project.

Comment: The thousands grouping flag is mentioned in the GCC (actually libc) docs here: http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/libc/Integer-Conversions.html#Integer-Conversions  (but without very much detail).  Of course, your arduino target might not have the full `libc` implementation available to it.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe not best algorithm, but here's an implementation example (standard C):

```
char* formatLong(long toBeFormatted)
{
    // Get the string representation as is
    char* buffer = (char*) malloc(sizeof(long));
    ltoa(toBeFormatted, buffer, 10);

    // Calculate how much commas there will be
    unsigned int buff_length = strlen(buffer);
    unsigned int num_commas = buff_length / 3;
    unsigned int digits_left = buff_length % 3;
    if (digits_left == 0)
    {
        num_commas--;
    }

    // Allocate space for final string representation
    unsigned int final_length = buff_length + num_commas + 1;
    char* final = (char*) malloc(final_length);
    memset(final, 0, final_length);

    // Parse strings from last to first to count positions
    int final_pos = final_length - 2;
    int buff_pos = buff_length - 1;
    int i = 0;
    while(final_pos >= 0)
    {
        final[final_pos--] = buffer[buff_pos--];
        i++;
        if (i % 3 == 0)
        {
            final[final_pos--] = ',';
        }
    }

    // Free obsolete memory and return buffer
    free(buffer);
    return final;
}
```

Comment: If anyone comes with a shorter/faster algorithm, please post it!

Comment: I've tried it and it seems to work in some way. I had problem on the last digit; printing 15195 through your function returns 15,19ç where the last character is certainly something spurious.

Comment: Works fine in x86. You can try subsituting `final[final_pos--] = buffer[buff_pos--]` with a _memcpy()_...

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

```
std::string formatLong(long l) {
    int power = 0;
    while (l / (pow(1000, power)) { power += 1; }

    power -= 1;

    std::stringstream s;
    while (power) {
         s <<  l / pow(1000, power);
         s << ",";
         l % (pow(1000, power));
         power -= 1;
    }
    return s->str();
}
```

The code is a shot from the hip, but the idea should work.

Answer (score 0):

maybe can help you..
i use this sketch to make thousands separator on arduino LCD.

```
//&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&
//TULISAN DENGAN SPARATOR BELI BBM
//&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&
    void TulisanDesimalBeli(char customKey, String DataStr)
{
  c=DataStr.length();
    if (c<=7)
    {
      if (c<4)
       {
       lcd.print(customKey);
       }  
       else if (c==4)
       {
        DataStr1=DataStr;
        DataStr.remove(c-3);
        DataStr1.remove(0,(c-3));
        DataStr+="." + DataStr1;
        lcd.setCursor(0,1);
        lcd.print("Jml:Rp.");
        lcd.print(DataStr);
        }
        else if ((c>4)&&(c<=6))
        {
        DataStr1=DataStr;
        DataStr.remove(c-3);
        DataStr1.remove(0,(c-3));
        DataStr+="." + DataStr1;
        lcd.setCursor(0,1);
        lcd.print("Jml:Rp.");
        lcd.print(DataStr);
        }
        else if (c>6)
        {
        DataStr1=DataStr;
        DataStr.remove(c-3);
        DataStr1.remove(0,(c-3));
        DataStr+="." + DataStr1;

        DataStr1=DataStr;
        DataStr.remove((c-6));
        DataStr1.remove(0,(c-6));
        DataStr+="." + DataStr1;

        lcd.setCursor(0,1);
        lcd.print("Jml:Rp.");
        lcd.print(DataStr);
        }
    }
    }
```

and this sketch thal called the subroutine (void TulisanDesimaBeli)

```
if ((customKey<='9')&&(customKey>='0'))
    { 
      DataStr+=customKey;
      TulisanDesimalBeli(customKey,DataStr);
      a=(int)customKey&0x0F;
      HarBel=HarBel*10;
      HarBel=HarBel+a;
     }
```

sorry, my english is worst, you can watch on https://youtu.be/baYdiqqfr3c minutes 1.30

or visit my web on http://www.radixrobotic.id/project/arduino-tiket-printer-epson-tm-u220/

regrad.